# Is the Sobolev embedding $W^{l,2}(\mathbb{R}^d) \rightarrow C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

In p. 508 of the paper : http://www.jstor.org/stable/2243484 , it is mentioned that if $2l \geq d$, the embedding $W^{l,2}(\mathbb{R}^d) \rightarrow C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is compact, where $W^{l,2}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the $(l,2)-$Sobolev space on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the space of continuous functions $\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ vanishing at infinity.

I have tried to look in many references but haven't found this. So is it true or not?

Comment: The standard counterexample, in those things, is made up by translating a bump function in space. This should disprove compactness of that embedding.

Comment: Either the author of that paper made a mistake, or used strange notation. Sobolev embedding yields a compact embedding $W^{l,2}(\mathbb{R}^d) \rightarrow C^m(\mathbb{R}^d)$, where $m < n - l/2$. Perhaps the author takes $m = 0$ and uses a subscript where there is normally a superscript?

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer, would you maybe have a reference about what you said? PS: no, it's not a strange notation because he says that $C_0$ is Banach, so he really doesn't mean $"C"$

Comment: Yeah, I mean $d$. See any textbook on partial differential equations, such as *Partial Differential Equations* by Evans, or *Elliptic partial differential equations of second order* by Gilbarg and Trudinger. You should probably just be able to find the result by googling the Sobolev embedding theorem.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong: Are you sure that the imbedding is compact? We are talking of spaces on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^d$ here.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, You're right, perhaps I've misstated the embedding theorem. I think we in fact have compact embedding only into $C^{0, \alpha}$, where $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is sufficiently small; furthermore we require $2l > d$. However, I do not think the embedding theorem is impeded by spaces on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong What about Giuseppe's counterexample? Embedding theorems hold. But _compactness_ (Rellich-Kondrachov and such) almost always requires the domain to have compact closure.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: why not post your first comment as an answer? It answers the question explicitly asked by the OP.

Comment: @WillieWong, Yes, you're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true, I think that there are two errors.

The first is that you do *not* have the embedding 
$$\tag{1}W^{l,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)\subset C_o(\mathbb{R}^d)$$
in the critical case $lp=d$. You can find more information about this in Evans' book on PDE, 2nd edition, pag. 280 "The borderline case $p=n$".

The second error is that the embedding (1), which holds when $lp>d$, is *not* compact. To wit, fix a function $\phi\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and a unit vector $u\in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$. Define 
$$\phi_n(x)=\phi(x-nu).$$
This is a bounded sequence in $W^{l,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ which does not have any uniformly convergent subsequence, meaning that the embedding (1) is not compact.